# How to remove leading or trailing spaces from copy/paste operations?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I usually have to copy/paste test from web pages (or other places) and paste it into HTML forms (usually Chrome).

The problem is that ofter I do end-up with a text that has additional leading or trailing spaces.

Is there a way to prevent this, by default? Like an OS X application or Chrome extension that can trick how paste works?

Answer (score 3):

There´s an app for that.
[ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/) besides keeping a clipboard history it is possible to assign scripts to the entries.
(1) You copy as usual
(2) click on ClipMenu's status bar icon, select your latest entry, and use a user-selectable key-click command to perform LTrim or RTrim on the entry.
[ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/) is freeware.

Comment: Thanks, this almost solves the problem, but still I cannot make it work when I press `Cmd+V` or doing a right-mouse-click and selecte Paste.

Comment: The original webpage is no longer maintained and app download 404's. Via https://github.com/ClipMenu/ClipMenu/issues/17 I found a working fork: https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy but it does not support clipboard trimming.